# Get Twitter user tweets using API with OAuth and PHP

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

I am looking to get a single user's tweets through PHP.  Currently I am using the RSS object

```
$string = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=' . $screenname . '&count=' . $tweetCount;
```

However, I want to prepare for when the API changes to authentication only.  How do I make this change so when the API switches over everything will still work?

Answer (score 1):

Try using these libraries: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php

One of them has oauth support.